# Elastic search equivalent query needed to find distinct values in a column in version 1.7.5

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-2.0

I have a elastic search index having columns
a, b, c
Need to find the elastic search query equivalent of 
select distinct c from tablename;
ES version is 1.7.5

Answer (score 0):

You could use facets:

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.7/search-facets.html

You should also really consider upgrading to a newer version.